# Pre-filling values of a form using json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JSON object something like this `{"expiry_year":"15","number":"411111","month":"12","cvn":"456"}`

Now on some callback I am getting this value. My requirement is to put these values in a from by using MAP so in future if some one change DOM id it won't affect the page.

To achieve this I am trying like this

```
var domWithValueMap = {
              "number" : "number",
              "cnv" : "cnv",
              "month" : "expiry_month",
              "expiry_year" : "expiry_year"
          }
```

In above hash

```
var domWithValueMap = {
              "keys of json obg" : "id of DOM",

          }
```

and so on..

My div id's are : number,expiry_year,month and cvn.

Then after I was trying to match whether the keys are exists or not using this

```
   domWithValueMap.hasOwnProperty(key);
```

After this I gets confused how to proceed. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var values = {"expiry_year":"15","number":"411111","month":"12","cvn":"456"};
for(var key in values){
    document.getElementById(domWithValueMap[key]).value = values[key];
}
```

A little longer, with comments:

```
var values = {"expiry_year":"15","number":"411111","month":"12","cvn":"456"};
for(var key in values){                       // Loop through your values,
    var id = domWithValueMap[key]             // Get the element ID from the value's key,
    var element = document.getElementById(id) // Get the element,
    element.value = values[key];              // Set teh value of the element.
}
```